# Switching fragments in navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have my main Activity in this way:

```
public class EntryPoint extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener
```

And two fragments that I only want to switch when you select one item in the navigation bar, so I have this method that is working in the Nexus 7 (target version 4.2.2) but not in the Xperia Neo V (target version 4.0.3). The first fragment appear without problem, but when I change to the other fragment, I debugged it and it doesn't execute the method onCreate or onCreateView. And thats why it through an exception when trying to access to the list in the fragments. The wierd thing is that in the Nexus 7 works perfect but in the SonyEriccson no.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
    // container view.

    int section = position + 1;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (section == 1) {
        ft.add(R.id.container,new FavCityListFragment());

    } else if (section == 2) {
        ft.remove(getFav());
        ft.add(R.id.container,new CityListFragment());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

    }
    ft.commit();
    return true;
}
```

The two fragments are like this one:

```
public class CityListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements
    com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
```

And the container:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EntryPoint"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking to [Ismael Reyes](https://twitter.com/kix2902), he found the answer:

Is this issue in Android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18594

And to answer it:

> "[...] editing src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/LoaderCustomSupport.java to remove the references to OnQueryTextListener and the onCreateOptionsMenu, onQueryTextChange, and onQueryTextSubmit functions [...]" Dianne Hackborn